# Unity UI can get text from label but can not set it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following property and method:

```
public Text newScore;

public void SaveScore(){
    int score = int.Parse(newScore.text);
    newScore.text = "";
    /* Snipped: Save the value to the database */
}
```

I then have a gameobject with a button component on it. In the onClick of that button I attach the above script, and when I click on the button I am able to get the text from the Text component, but I then can not reset the text to an empty string (or anything else). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: And you sure the text has no reference anywhere else?

Comment: Maybe it breaks silently on int score = int.Parse(newScore.text); and does not go to newScore.text = "";. Since you might handle that exception on caller thread.

Comment: I have code after I call `newScore.text = ""` and that code runs

Comment: Try adding a debug after the line to check the content of text.

Comment: @fafase Yup it is only in that file in that one spot

Comment: @fafase the debug shows the numbers entered, an not an empty string.

Comment: Try adding a space to your string, could be that it does a IsNullOrEmpty check. Would be a bad design from unity dev but well...

Comment: I have tried that and doesn't work I have also tried random characters. I also tried setting it in the `Update`, nothing seems to be resetting the value...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Have you tried putting `newScore.text = ""` before `int score = int.Parse(newScore.text);`

Comment: It does work fine for me. Make sure you don't have anything using it somewhere or some script added twice.

Comment: Just to say, it does work so it has to be something you done wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @Carl placing it before doesn't reset, but it still grabs it from the input.

Comment: I think there is no problem here. Please check somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with an `InputField` the component has a `text` field.

Instead of using the child `GameObject` with the `Text` component to change the value, use the `InputField`'s `text` field.

```
public InputField newScore;

public void SaveScore(){
    int score = int.Parse(newScore.text);
    newScore.text = "";
    /* Snipped: Save the value to the database */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an InputField , if so use something like this instead:

```
InputField field;
void Start () 
{
    field.text = "";
}
```